# Initializing Inherited Class Through Derived Constructor's Arguments (C#)

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, stream, filestream

Hell, the title probably wasn't the best, but I'm a fairly new programmer and haven't had much experience with inherited classes.  I'm trying to initialize a class (my own Stream derived from the normal FileStream class) and have the option of initializing the base from the derived's arguments.  For example...

```
public class Example : FileStream
{
public Example(FileStream FS) : base = FS
}
```

Obviously I can't just do that, but it best shows what I'd *like* to do.  The main reason why I'm doing this is because of contradicting streams -- and what I mean by that is that within this class, another class automatically opens the file (and does some reading and whatnot) and I get thrown an exception that the file is inaccessible.  Maybe I'm doing this wrong, but thanks for everyone's time!

Comment: what are you trying to do by extending FileStream . I think its sufficient enough to handle File related operations. Please explain what you want to accomplish by doing this. And what problem are you facing

Comment: Just for fun, C++ syntax: public ref class Example : public FileStream
{
public: Example(FileStream^ stream) : base(stream) { /* something sould goes here, if any */}
}

Comment: @Artur: I don’t have C++ handy, but that probably won’t compile there either.

Comment: if you are carrying some functionality using FileStream methods, like Write(byte[], ..), but want to return deserialized object already or serialize it, you do not need the base class iheritace, IMHO. Create your own class and pass FileStream handle to its methods doing the all dirty job for POCO serialization/deserialization. It's more generic approach.

Comment: @Artur: Well, the C# equivalent doesn’t compile because `FileStream` doesn’t have a constructor that takes a `FileStream` as an argument. If C++ does have such a constructor, what does it do and what is it for?

Comment: @Shekhar to explain very quickly: I'm trying to write up a custom stream to basically "mount" a non-sequential file that is held within another file on a disk in my application.

Comment: HaHa! public class Example : FileStream { FileStream _base; public Example(FileStream FS) : base() { _base = FS; } }

Comment: @user455678: If so, than you are completely in a wrong way!!!

Comment: @Artur To be 100% honest: I figured as much.  Mind sharing how you'd go about it?

Comment: @user455678: It is not physically possible to open file stream inside the file stream, unlike other OS'es, windows do not suppot hierarchical FS, you can try memory-mapped files, you own codecs (like WMA, or MP3) inside the FS, or use any of the known virtualization technologies.

Comment: @Artur Well basically what I'm doing is working the stream around the other stream.  So... the best way for me to explain what I'm doing is I am going to manipulate the base stream to where it acts as a sequential file.  I know that probably made no sense at all, but it works :).  Thanks again Timwi, Artur!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t do that, no. But for `Stream` specifically, you can derive from `Stream`, store the `FileStream` in a private field and pass all the method calls to it:

```
public class Example : Stream
{
    private Stream _underlying;

    public Example(Stream underlying) { _underlying = underlying; }

    // Do the following for all the methods in Stream
    public override int Read(...) { return _underlying.Read(...); }
}
```

If you move the text cursor to the word `Stream` after the `Example :`, press Alt+Shift+F10 and choose “Implement abstract class Stream”, it will generate all the method declarations for you, but you will still have to change all the `throw new NotImplementedException()` into the proper calls to `_underlying`.

Comment: You said something up here, so...

It is not physically possible to open file stream inside the file stream, unlike other OS'es, windows do not suppot hierarchical FS, you can try memory-mapped files, you own codecs (like WMA, or MP3) inside the FS, or use any of the known virtualization technologies.

Answer (score -1):

As you might expected, you're making a mistake in the syntax, you can
help with this example.

```
public class SomeClassA
{
    public int foo1;
    public string foo2;
    public SomeClassA(int foo1, string foo2)
    {
        this.foo1 = foo1;
        this.foo2 = foo2;
    }
}
public class SomeClassB : SomeClassA
{
    public SomeClassB(int arg1, string arg2)
        : base(arg1, arg2)
    { }
}
```

Comment: This doesn’t help in his case. He doesn’t want to initialise from arguments, but from an existing instance.

Comment: Thanks, but please review what I wrote to Shekhar_Pro above. edit: yes, what Timwi said.